# Combine two group bys?

Tags: postgresql

I have two queries:

```
SELECT to_char(pubdate, 'YYYY-MM') pub_month, COUNT(*) total 
FROM books 
GROUP BY pub_month;
```

and

```
SELECT to_char(pubdate, 'YYYY-MM') pub_month, COUNT(*) total_bought 
FROM books 
WHERE purchased=true 
GROUP BY pub_month;
```

Is there any way to combine them so that the result is

```
+-----------+-------+--------------
| pub_month | total | total_bought 
+-----------+-------+--------------
|   2018-10 |     5 |            2
|   2018-09 |    10 |            7
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`FILTER`](https://modern-sql.com/feature/filter) clause:

> The filter clause extends aggregate functions (sum, avg, count, …) by an additional where clause. **The result of the aggregate is built from only the rows that satisfy the additional where clause too.**

```
SELECT to_char(pubdate, 'YYYY-MM') pub_month
    , COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE purchased) total_bought
    , COUNT(*) total 
FROM books 
GROUP BY pub_month;
```

or conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT to_char(pubdate, 'YYYY-MM') pub_month
    , SUM(CASE WHEN purchased THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) total_bought
    , COUNT(*) total 
FROM books 
GROUP BY pub_month;
```

---

Additional note: `WHERE purchased=true` <=> `WHERE purchased`

Comment: First case is SQL:2003 std, but as of this date only supported in postgresql (fine by tags on this Q), the other is generally supported in all dialects.

Comment: @CadeRoux Yes, unfortunately only PostgreSQL and newest version of SQLite(limited to windowed version only): https://modern-sql.com/feature/filter

Comment: Well, I'm using PostgreSQL and love it, so that is why I picked this answer over the others which will work in other RDBMs.

Answer (score 2):

You can make it in one sql query.

```
SELECT to_char(pubdate, 'YYYY-MM') pub_month, COUNT(*) total , 
       sum(case when purchased=true then 1 else 0 end) total_bought 
FROM books 
GROUP BY pub_month;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT to_char(pubdate, 'YYYY-MM') pub_month
           , COUNT(*) total
           , SUM(CASE WHEN purchased=true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) total_bought 
FROM books 
GROUP BY pub_month;
```

Comment: Wow this is totally amazing!